# Why getting current git branch in command substitution is not the latest?

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to create an alias in order to open a url with my git branch name like:

`alias jira="echo https://atlassian.net/browse/$(git branch --show-current)"`

But the `git branch --show-current` when used in this substitution is always one branch late when I change branch... But the command itself show the actual current branch.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Use single quotes to prevent the substitution at alias definition: `alias jira='echo https://atlassian.net/browse/$(git branch --show-current)'`. But prefer a function aliases are kind of obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a shell function :

```
jira () {
    echo https://atlassian.net/browse/$(git branch --show-current)
}
```

The code will be executed and evaluated on each call to that function.

---

You say "the alias is one branch late", but chances are the alias is computed and stored when your shell is started. If you change branch 3 times, does the branch name printed by your alias change at all ?

Comment: arf you're right it's not updating at all... I think I tried too many things at once :) By the way thank you, the function way works great !